# XPath (PHP Dom) - How to find span with attribute and retrieve previous siblings

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

Given the following excerpt of a HTML document:

```
<p>
<span m='1900'>INTERVIEWER: Today</span> 
<span m='2180'>is</span> 
<span m='2330'>October</span> 
<span m='2940'>31,</span> 
<span m='3940'>2008.</span> 
<span m='5750'>I'm</span> 
<span m='6010'>Interviewing</span> 
<span m='7700'>for</span> 
<span m='7920'>the</span> 
<span m='8050'>organisation's</span> 
<span m='9360'>sesquicentennial</span> 
<span m='10410'>Oral</span> 
<span m='10690'>History</span> 
<span m='11170'>project,</span> 
<span m='12380'>talking</span> 
<span m='12760'>about</span> 
<span m='12950'>how</span> 
<span m='13470'>things</span>
</p>
```

How can I extract the `<span>` with a specific value for the `m` attribute along with 5 of the previous siblings?

I have the following code so far, which correctly identifies the span:

```
$xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']";
$span = $xpath->query($xpath_query);
```

How can I retrieve the previous siblings?

**EDIT:**

My ultimate aim is to create a HTML string that contains the match plus the previous 5 siblings and the next 5 siblings.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
      $output_doc = new DOMDocument;

      $xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']/preceding-sibling::span[position() < 5]";
      $previous_spans = $xpath->query($xpath_query);

      foreach($previous_spans as $previous_span) {
        $output_doc->appendChild($previous_span);
      }

      $xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']";
      $span = $xpath->query($xpath_query);
      $output_doc->appendChild($span);

      $xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']/following-sibling::span[position() < 5]";
      $next_spans = $xpath->query($xpath_query);

      foreach($next_spans as $next_span) {
        $output_doc->appendChild($next_span);
      }
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here is the code I used in the end to get it working:

```
function get_snippets($transcript, $timestamps) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadHTML($transcript);

    $output = array();

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    foreach($timestamps as $timestamp) {

      $xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']/preceding-sibling::span[position() < 10]";
      $previous_spans = $xpath->query($xpath_query);

      foreach($previous_spans as $previous_span) {
        $output[$timestamp] = $output[$timestamp] . ih_video_outer_html($previous_span);
      }

      $xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']";
      $span = $xpath->query($xpath_query);

      foreach($span as $match) {
        $output[$timestamp] = $output[$timestamp] . ih_video_outer_html($match);
      }

      $xpath_query = "//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']/following-sibling::span[position() < 10]";
      $next_spans = $xpath->query($xpath_query);

      foreach($next_spans as $next_span) {
        $output[$timestamp] = $output[$timestamp] . ih_video_outer_html($next_span);
      }
    }
}

function ih_video_outer_html($e) {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($e, true));
  return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Just add `preceding-sibling::span` to your existing query construct...to make it like `"//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']/preceding-sibling::span"`...

Comment: Nice!  Does that give me all previous siblings?  I can then loop through an pickout the last 5?

Comment: `"//span[@m='" . $timestamp . "']/preceding-sibling::span[position() &lt; 5]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//span[@m=12950] | //span[@m=12950]/preceding-sibling::span[position() < 6]
```

//span[@m=12950] -  take your item

//span[@m=12950]/preceding-sibling::span - add previous spans

[position() < 6] - not far than 5 items

Comment: @Cylian of cause, it's just a stupid habit that came from the regex :)

Comment: Great, thank you.  How can I add the selected elements to a new doc?  My aim is to output the previous 5 spans plus the matching span plus the next 5 spans as a string.

Comment: do you want to make xml or string result? What the format in the second case?

Comment: I'm looking to output a HTML string (I'm passing to client for display on a web page). For `m` value `7700` I need the following: `<span m='2330'>October</span> 
<span m='2940'>31,</span> 
<span m='3940'>2008.</span> 
<span m='5750'>I'm</span> 
<span m='6010'>Interviewing</span> 
<span m='7700'>for</span> 
<span m='7920'>the</span> 
<span m='8050'>organisation's</span> 
<span m='9360'>sesquicentennial</span> 
<span m='10410'>Oral</span> 
<span m='10690'>History</span> `

Comment: I've updated the question with the code I have so far but I receive an error `DOMException: Wrong Document Error in DOMNode->appendChild()`

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much!  I managed to get it working the way I wanted based on your code.  I've posted the code I used to my question.